# Checking memory allocation in Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, memory-leaks, instruments

I've cleared my app of leaks using the leaks tool, but I still notice that the objectalloc tool jumps up in the number of objects allocated and footprint when I switch views.

I'm especially seeing high numbers of:

GeneralBlock-16 with mostly Foundation responsible with caller NSLogv

and

GeneralBlock-0 with mostly QuartzCore responsible

Any tips on what I can do to further debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The ObjectAlloc tool is designed to graph total object allocation over time, and it doesn't take deallocations into account. Essentially: **it will always go up**.

What you can do is look at the Net Bytes and # Net columns. These columns **will** adjust based on the number of objects you deallocate, and if you're concerned about total object allocation you can use these to gauge your program's performance.

You can take a look at [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1574033) on the Apple Support forums - it deals more with what Instruments measures and how you can test your app.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question was unclear. I'm aware that object allocation always goes up, however I was referring to Net Bytes and #Net which also never go down, which is worrying. Pushing views in a navigation controllers increases these numbers greatly, whilst popping views doesn't decrease them.

Also the sheer number of GeneralBlock-0 is disturbing. I really want to know why so many 0-bit objects are in existance.

Comment: This isn't quite correct; you can configure the Allocations instrument to only track live allocations.  In that case, the columns will reflect exactly what is in memory right now.

Comment: bbum is right, in Xcode 4, the default Allocations template in Instrument shows 'All Allocations' broken down into columns, displaying both Live Bytes and Overall Bytes.

Answer (score 6):

You should check out http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=311.

Great video from WWDC 2010 about memory analysis with Instruments.