# Instruments Object Alloc tool GRAPH question

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, instruments

I'm getting mixed info regarding the GRAPH of the Object Alloc tool in Instruments...

On one hand, I've heard several [people claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061235/checking-memory-allocation-in-instruments) (<-- see thread) that the graph *doesn't take deallocations into account and it will always rise*. Yet when I use it myself, I can see that it sometimes DOES go down, particularly when I release a resource. So, can someone please tell me what the heck I am looking at when I see the graph in the Object Alloc tool?

And if you, too, are going to re-assert the well-spread claim that the graph indeed *does not* take deallocations into account, please do us laypeople a favor and be very thorough in your explanation -- taking special care to address exactly what you assume the graph to be doing when it does go DOWN, and it does.

*Refer to the answer in this thread:
[Checking memory allocation in Instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061235/checking-memory-allocation-in-instruments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends *entirely* on how you configure the allocations instrument.   If you click the little (i) on the Allocations instrument, you'll see a configuration sheet like the one below.

If you only want to track live allocations, then turn that on!   If you want to record every last retain/release (very useful for figuring out zombies and over-retains), you can turn that on, too!

It even has filtration;   filter down to just your objects, if you want.

[image]

Comment: Can't find the *"little (i)"* in Instruments 8.3.2 but found the same settings in `Pull Down Menu > File > Recording Options`.